# Changing cursor color based on a minor mode

Tags: emacs, mode

I have written a minor-mode, it defines some key bindings and does some initialization.  The mode properly sets up Navi-mode and Navi-mode-map.

How do I enhance this minor-mode to change the color of the cursor when Navi-mode is enabled, and change it back whenever the mode is disabled?  Can I use the hook Navi-mode-hook?

Comment: @TreyJackson, I do not feel like the edit of the title is doing the question justice. I am not only interested in changing the cursor color, but more generally how to toggle things when you enter/exit a mode.

Comment: Sorry about that, please edit my edits if you desire.  That was the only concrete example you gave, what else do you want to toggle?  Key bindings are already managed for you by the minor mode system...  Specifics are needed because it (can) determine the solution.

Comment: I did not have something in mind, other than some visual changes. Though I get you, it is not easy to think of something. Keyboard, font-lock-faces, mode-line are done in a different way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
(define-minor-mode foo-mode "doodad" :lighter ""
  (if foo-mode
      (setq cursor-type 'bar)
    (setq cursor-type (default-value 'cursor-type))))
```

Or, if you anticipate `cursor-type` to already have a non-default value, you can save it when the mode is enabled and restore the saved value when it's disabled.

Comment: Where do I put this `if` statement in my minor mode function?

Comment: I have the defun, mode name, description, init value 0, Modeline indiciator, minor mode keymap, then `:global t`. I tried to put this `if` statement below this `:global t`, but it did not work.

Comment: If your minor mode is global, replace `setq` with `setq-default`. And `default-value` won't help in this case, so when disabling, you'll need to either restore the value from a separate var, or just set it to `t`, if the mode is just for your own use.

Answer (score 3):

Either you have total control of the minor mode (because you wrote it), and you can embed this behaviour directly in your minor-mode function as explained in Dmitry's answer:

```lisp
(define-minor-mode navi-mode
  "Navi mode does wonderful things"
  :lighter " Navi"
  :global t
  :init-value 0

  (if navi-mode
      (progn
        (setq old-cursor-color (cdr (assoc 'cursor-color (frame-parameters))))
        (set-cursor-color "red"))
    (set-cursor-color old-cursor-color)))
```

Or you don't control the minor mode definition and you'll have to use a hook:

```lisp
(defun navi-change-cursor-color ()
  (if navi-mode
      (progn
        (setq old-cursor-color (cdr (assoc 'cursor-color (frame-parameters))))
        (set-cursor-color "red"))
    (set-cursor-color old-cursor-color)))

(add-hook 'navi-mode-hook 'navi-change-cursor-color)
```

Comment: In addition to `foo-mode-hook`, `define-minor-mode` defines separate `foo-mode-on-hook` and `foo-mode-off-hook`.

Comment: @Dmitry You're entirely right. Actually I was wrong and hooks are always run when the mode is toggled, so they can be used as well. Just for the sake of completeness, I edited my answer to reflect this.