# how set comment-start and comment-end in a emacs minor mode?

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

I'm trying to create a **minor mode** for [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) the syntax is very similar to django and I want to change the values of the comment style to use {# and #}

If I do

```
(setq comment-start "{#")
(setq comment-end "#}")
```

run correctly, but when change to lisp-mode the comment-end remains "#}" instead of ""

The code is [here](https://github.com/mgallego/twig.el/blob/master/twig.el)

Thanks

Comment: Sounds to me like you should create a derived major mode instead.

Comment: @tripleee how will that help?

Comment: Because then you have a mechanism for only the buffers in which this mode is active.  Sounds like one of the available Django modes would be a good starting point; https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/Emacs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something along the lines of an answer on [how to change the cursor based on a minor mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14145348/6148):

```
(defvar twig-mode-previous-comments nil
  "Storage for comment start/end that was before twig mode was enabled")
(define-minor-mode twig-mode "twig" :lighter ""
  (unless twig-mode-previous-comments
    (set (make-local-variable 'twig-mode-previous-comments) (cons comment-start comment-end)))
  (if twig-mode
      (progn
        (set (make-local-variable 'comment-start) "{#")
        (set (make-local-variable 'comment-end) "#}"))
    (setq comment-start (car twig-mode-previous-comments))
    (setq comment-end (cdr twig-mode-previous-comments))))
```

Comment: Instead of using `defvar` + `make-local-variable` you can simply use `defvar-local`.

Comment: @Daimrod `defvar-local` isn't a built-in for Emacs, and the packages that implement something like that (e.g. `ediff-defvar-local` simply do it with a `defvar` and a `make-variable-buffer-local`)

Comment: It's not built-in but it's defined in `subr.el` which is part of GNU Emacs, close enough™ for me. Anyway, your version works too.

Comment: @Daimrod Hmmm... Interesting, I don't see it in my copy of 24.2 (just downloaded it), but it's there in the repository (since May).

Comment: @Trey Jackson: `defvar-local` (and other similar commands like `setq-local`) are new in the yet-to-be-released Emacs 24.3.

Comment: @TreyJackson `comment-start` and `comment-end` are not local by default.  You'll need to make these buffer local as suggested by sds to avoid conflicts with other modes.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make them `buffer-local` by adding this:

```
(set (make-local-variable 'comment-start) "{#")
(set (make-local-variable 'comment-end) "#}")
```

to the `define-minor-mode` body.